# How do you replace multiple instances of '+' in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a URL that I need to manipulate. I cant seem to replace all the '+' within a query string with whitespace.

```
var url = window.location.replace(/+/g, ' ');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Or is there a better method?

Comment: `+` is a special regex characters.

Comment: Plus is a special regex character. Escape it.

Answer (score 4):

[`replace()` is a method on `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Methods), but it's not [the one you think](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). You want call `replace()` on [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties).

```
var url = window.location.href.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

As [Vega answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604092/139010), note that you also need to escape the `+` because of its [special meaning as a quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: replace won't replace all occurrences, but +1 for `window.location.replace`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `+`. `+` has a special meaning in regEx.

```
var url = window.location.href.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

**Edit:** Changed to `.href`

Comment: this is perfect, why does it have a different meaning if you mind me asking?

Comment: @CecilTheodore because it's part of the regex syntax.

Comment: @CecilTheodore: It's quantifier. It means "match the preceding pattern one or more times". I recommend to have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: `+` is a quantifier in regEx which means it will test for any character before `+` for 1 or more occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative if you don't need to run it thousands of times.

```
var url = window.location.href.split('+').join(' ');
```

The reason I mentioned how often it is run is this will be a little slower than a regex in Firefox, a fair bit slower in chrome and oddly faster in Opera according to the tests here: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split-join

So for a simple URL change it should be fine to use that syntax.